# No audio from omxplayer when running mp4 from shell script

Tags: omxplayer, audio-playback

On PI 4 I can run a video from terminal :

```
$ omxplayer -o alsa video.mp4
```

audio is ok.

When I add this exact line in a bash file it plays the video but no sound.  I have tried all variations of -o.   Using a BT speaker.

Also tried using VLC (same exact issue).